# rails commands and rake are dumping unwanted list of all gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It is very strange. I even tried a brand new project:

```
rails new abc
cd abc
rails s
```

The output is:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
active_support/descendants_tracker
active_support/core_ext/module/delegation
active_support/core_ext/object/to_param
active_support/core_ext/regexp
... lots more here
active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options
rack/utils
action_controller/metal/exceptions
[2015-04-23 19:35:42] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-04-23 19:35:42] INFO  ruby 2.1.2 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
[2015-04-23 19:35:42] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=12738 port=3000
```

It doesn't break anything, but it makes reading output to debug very difficult.

It happens for all usage of `rails` and `rake`, in or out of `bundle exec`, but not `bundle` commands like `bundle list` or `bundle install`

Comment: Doesn't happen by default. Check if there are any `puts` statements in the code both in the app code, and the gems code.

Comment: Thanks Prakash. I did check, didn't find anything. I did a really clean `rails new abc`, and then `cd abc; rails s`. So there is absolutely no app code, the gems are all coming from rubygems and using the default as created by rails new. Could it be something global in my rails installation? Environment?

Comment: I think it is most likely in a gem that is not installed as part of `rails new`. Try `cd ``bundle show rails``; `cd ..`; grep -r puts *` ; should show up at least 1 line.

Comment: Goes to my global rails at `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rails-4.1.1` so `grep` is going to show for every gem on my system, not just those included in a native project. Nonetheless, the `grep` shows 9701 lines from 2379 files.

Comment: 9701 `puts` statements??

Comment: 9701 lines with `puts` in it. Some are comments, etc. but yes, 9701 lines. But I don't get how it helps. These could be legitimate `puts` as part of a gem, not necessarily dumping all of my gems.

Answer (score 0):

Strangest thing... but it went away when I updated from rails 4.1.1 to rails 4.2.1